# How to combine or merge two sparse vectors in Spark using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, sparse-matrix, apache-spark-mllib

I used the Java's API, i.e. Apache-Spark 1.2.0, and created two parse vectors as follows.

```
Vector v1 = Vectors.sparse(3, new int[]{0, 2}, new double[]{1.0, 3.0});
Vector v2 = Vectors.sparse(2, new int[]{0, 1}, new double[]{4,5});
```

How can I get a new vector `v3` that is formed by combining `v1` and `v2`, so the result should be: `(5, [0,2,3,4],[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])`

Comment: you could write a method that adds the first number and concats the arrays?

Comment: that's also doable. I'm wondering whether there is an existing utility in spark mllib for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem has been one year and is still pending. Here, I solved the problem by writing a helper function myself, as follows.

```
public static SparseVector combineSparseVectors(SparseVector... svs) {
    int size = 0;
    int nonzeros = 0;
    for (SparseVector sv : svs) {
        size += sv.size();
        nonzeros += sv.indices().length;
    }

    if (nonzeros != 0) {
        int[] indices = new int[nonzeros];
        double[] values = new double[nonzeros];

        int pointer_D = 0;
        int totalPt_D = 0;
        int pointer_V = 0;
        for (SparseVector sv : svs) {
            int[] indicesSV = sv.indices();
            for (int i : indicesSV) {
                indices[pointer_D++] = i + totalPt_D;
            }
            totalPt_D += sv.size();

            double[] valuesSV = sv.values();
            for (double d : valuesSV) {
                values[pointer_V++] = d;
            }

        }
        return new SparseVector(size, indices, values);
    } else {
        System.out.println("all zeroes");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from HappyCoding, I just want to contribute my code in Python 3.x using `pyspark` and `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector


def concat_sparse_vectors(sparse_vectors):
    """
    Input:
        sparse_vectors (list): A list containing sparse vectors
    Output:
        A concatenated sparse vector
    """
    size = 0
    nonzeros = 0

    for vector in sparse_vectors:
        size += vector.size
        nonzeros += len(vector.indices)

    if nonzeros != 0:
        indices = np.zeros(nonzeros)
        values = np.zeros(nonzeros)

        pointer_D = 0 # A pointer pointing to the index where a non-zero value occupied in the 'values' array
        total_point_D = 0 # A displacement value for 'pointer_D' in the concatenated array which is 'values' in the code
        pointer_V = 0 # A pointer pointing to a value in the 'values' array in the code

        for vector in sparse_vectors:
            vector_indices = vector.indices
            for i in vector_indices:
                indices[pointer_D] = i + total_point_D
                pointer_D += 1

            total_point_D += vector.size

            vector_values = vector.values
            for value in vector_values:
                values[pointer_V] = value
                pointer_V += 1

        return SparseVector(size, indices, values)

    else:
        print('All zeros')
```